# JTable inserting data on an auto refresh scheme

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker

I have this JTable in which I have implemented an auto-refresh feature to display remaining time every 1minute or (60000l).

But I'm getting this problem when the row to be inserted isn't done yet (data encoding is done on the JTable itself) the data is lost. To prevent any data loss and without removing the auto-refresh feature.

Is it possible to pause the Thread (SwingWorker(Void, Void) was used for the auto-refresh feature) to give way that to be inserting / updating data is not lost?

Comment: what do you mean by "data encoding is done on the JTable itself"; this sentence looks like a design smell... Do you have some code to show us? In particular the swingworker and the table model would be important to check; also, normally a SwingWorker is used only once and seems not fit for your use case (auto-refresh) how do you use it?

Comment: Well, I created another thread inside the SwingWorker (mistaken). Going to make it a thread now...

Comment: Of course, you still have to keep in mind that changes to the JTable (or its TableModel) will have to be performed inside the EDT, so your thread has to use invokeLater/invokeAndWait to populate its results to the UI.

Comment: When I used SwingUtilies. The run method does not triggers and froze the application... (Sorry for the late reply.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the auto-refresh and the updating happen on the same thread. This will prevent the auto-refresh from executing until the current update is done.

The Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) is a good candidate, especially as Swing already contains the framework to queue operations on the EDT.

```
public void autorefresh() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
       new Runnable() { 
          ...
          // code to request refresh goes here. 
       }
    );
}
```